# How to create add new contacts in iOS like whatsapp

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, cncontactviewcontroller

I want to show an add new contact screen exactly the same as Whatsapp. I tried the default ios contact view controller **CNContactViewController**. But it is not the same as Whatsapp. Please give me a solution for this.
[image]

Comment: did you solve it bro if yes can you share it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Contacts Framework to create the new contact in code, thus allowing you to build your own ViewController from scratch:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts

Comment: This is more than likely what WhatsApp does.